# TV/Movie Identification: Evil person demanding the power source, people have scales falling off their eyes to see clearly

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, powers

I've been trying to find out the movie or TV show where one scene has a evil person wanting to obtain the power source (something of great power).

It is like a kid's sci fi show so this evil person looks a bit funny.

Then another scene is where a boy does something and suddenly everybody has scales falling off their eyes and they can see everything clearly.

I saw this about a few years back on TV.

Comment: This is horribly vague.  Can you give us more to go on?

Comment: When was "a few years back"? In which country did you watch it? What language? Was it live action or cartoon? Was it a kid's show (you say "like")? Do you remember what channel? What day / time was it shown? Was it a one off or a series?

Comment: I was terribly busy at that time and could only watch these two scenes on TV for a short while. I wanted to check the TV programme for the show name later but I forgot. It was maybe during a Sunday afternoon on Channel 5 in Singapore. Don't know if it's a one off or a series. It was live action with real actors. I suspected Nicolodean The Last Airbender movie but I didn't see these scenes. Could it be the TV series and which episode? It's in English. About 3-5 years back or so I guess

Comment: The Last Airbender TV series was a cartoon, so if the thing you saw was live-action it couldn't be that. Did it look like it had modern-looking CG effects? And when you say the evil person "looks a bit funny" do you just mean the actor's face, or was it makeup/prosthetics or some kind of unusual costume? Any description you can give of what people looked like (like what kind of clothes they wore) would be helpful. Also did the setting look modern or futuristic, or was it some low-tech fantasy world like The Last Airbender?

Comment: Settings look modern with sci-fi, not low-tech fantasy world. People look just human, no prosthetics. Clothes not as elaborate as Mockingjay type. More like Ultraman coloured clothes. Funny evil man as in rather innocent looking, evil showing in the makeup or the hairdo. Can't say much for the CG effects, maybe like Cloud Atlas standard.